# Eigenspace equals domain

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, generalized-eigenvector

In "Linear algebra done right", the author proves by induction that given a vector space $V$, and a linear operator $T$ on that vector space, $V$ is equal to the direct sum of the generalized eigenspaces of $T$.

However, the proof starts saying that if there is only 1 eigenvalue, the thesis is obvious. I cannot understand why it is obvious that, if there is only 1 eigenvalue, than there is an eigenspace equal to $V$

Comment: The proof in Linear Algebra Done Right does not start by saying that the result is obvious if there is only 1 eigenvalue. The proof starts by saying that the result is obvious if the dimension of V is 1 (in that case, the only operators on V are multiplications by scalars).

Comment: My apologies, professor. I do not know why I did not understand it in the first place. Now I feel ashamed. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Let $\lambda$ the unique eigenvalue then the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is

$$\chi_T(X)=(X-\lambda)^n$$
where $n=\dim V$ and so by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem $\chi_T(T)=0$ hence
$$V=\ker (T-\lambda I)^n$$